# Java EE - How to specify implementation on server

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am building a Java EE application with gradle and trying to remain agnostic to the actual implementation. I have added the JavaEE dependency like so..

```
group 'com.test.application'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

How would I specify the actual implementation so I can deploy this to a server?
My main concerns are JAX-RS and JPA implementations.

EDIT: I guess what I am trying to get at is why would anyone use 'javax:javaee-api:7.0' since its not a concrete implementation? I feel like i'm missing the point.

Comment: implementation of WHAT?

Answer (score 0):

Java EE containers should provide implementations for JPA and JAX-RS. For example:

- WildFly provides Hibernate and RESTEasy.
- GlassFish provides EclipseLink and Jersey.

In your dependency manager configuration file, you don't need to declare the concrete implementation dependency. However, if you need to use any class or interface provided by the concrete implementation, such dependency should be declared with the `provided` scope.